# Problem with Windows Boot Manager after using GParted

Tags: windows-7, bootloader

I Get the follow:

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix the problem:

1. Insert your windows installation disc and restart your computer.
2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
3. Click "Repair your computer."

If you do not have this disc, Contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for assistance.

Status: 0XC0000225

Info: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.

After I tried to expand the Windows partition. I dont know where I put the Windows 7 CD and I was wondering if anyone knew of any way of fixing this problem? I'm guessing I deleted something I shouldnt have deleted....... I actually wanted to get some more space at the expense of the recovery drive.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you do anything other than expanding the Windows partition? Were there any error messages during the expansion?

Comment: No error messages during expansion, and technically, I expanded and moved left...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you go [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/cc442495.aspx) and download a trial of Windows 7 Enterprise in the correct platform (X86 32-bit / X64 64-bit) that matches your system and burn it to disk or copy to a USB stick then simply run the startup repair tools.

This is a common problem that the startup repair can fix.

Answer (score -2):

Boot from an old Windows 98 boot floppy disk and run the command "fdisk /mbr" to write a new MBR on your hard drive. Then you will be able to boot Windows again. Use Windows Disk Manager to delete the partitions created during the install that did not work. Boot from the Linux CD and reinstall Linux using the install script to install the GRUB bootloader. You need to be careful about what partitions you install Linux into or you will wipe out your Windows installation.

Comment: I fail to see how this is relevant to the issue at hand...